# iOS Black Magnifying Glass

Tags: ios, iphone

I've been working on an iOS application and I came a cross with a bizarre behaviour.

[image: Black Magifying Glass]

This happens in iPhone 4 and 4S (I've not been able to test in iPhone 5 or 5S) but doesn't happen in the emulator or others apps in the same device. The interface is native (it's not a webapp).

Have anyone came across with this black spot?

EDIT: It happens in every TextField (secure or not)

Comment: Only with secure text fields?

Comment: @Wain no. Every text field causes this. Actually the only thing visible in the magnifying glass is the keyboard. Everything else is just pitch black

Comment: Are you doing anything custom with `UIWindow`s? Like changing the key window or presenting windows as subviews? I have the same issue, and suspect it to be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, and just solved it for myself.

In my app, I'm presenting different modes of my app in different `UIWindow`s, which involves creating different windows and changing which window is key and visible.

The text fields with the black eyeglass showing up were in a certain window, whose `windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal`.

Changing my `keyWindow`'s `windowLevel` did the trick for me:

`keyWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal + 0.1;`

Voila somehow it's working... I hope this helps!