# iOS Text Selection Magnifying Glass Color?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

In testing, I discovered the "magnifying glass" color for text selection in a view of my app is black, instead of being the normal magnifier.  I have no idea why this is, I don't believe I set it.

How can I change this back to the standard magnifying glass?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386132/ios-black-magnifying-glass

Comment: I am hoping for a better answer than someone dropping a text field in an empty project and saying "See it works for me".

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue - I suspect it has to do with some custom `UIWindow` management I'm doing, by changing the key window. Are you doing anything similar?

Comment: Nvm I fixed it for myself, hopefully yours is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37015259/2145198